# Perl Multi Threaded Program crashes Sporadically

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have written a program in Perl which makes use of multi threading. I am using this program to understand how multi threading is implemented in Perl.

First a brief overview of what the program intends to do: It will read a list of URLs from a text file, one at a time. For each URL, it will call a subroutine (passing the URL as a parameter) and send an HTTP HEAD request to it. Once it receives the HTTP Response headers, it will print the Server Header field from the response.

For each URL, it starts a new thread which calls the above subroutine.

The problem: The main issue is that the program crashes intermittently at times. It runs properly the other times. It appears to be unreliable code and I am sure there is a way to make it work reliably.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use WWW::Mechanize;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

open(INPUT,'<','urls.txt') || die("Couldn't open the file in read mode\n");

print "Starting main program\n";

my @threads;

while(my $url = <INPUT>)
{
    chomp $url;
    my $t = threads->new(\&sub1, $url);
    push(@threads,$t);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join;
}

print "End of main program\n";

sub sub1 {
    my $site = shift;
    sleep 1;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    $mech->agent_alias('Windows IE 6');

    # trap any error which occurs while sending an HTTP HEAD request to the site
    eval{$mech->head($site);};
    if($@)
    {
        print "Error connecting to: ".$site."\n";
    }

    my $response = $mech->response();

    print $site." => ".$response->header('Server'),"\n";
}
```

Questions:

How can I make this program work reliably and what is the reason for sporadic crashes?

What is the purpose of calling the join method of the thread object?

As per the documentation at the link below, it will wait for the thread execution to complete. Am I invoking the join method correctly?

http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

If there are any good programming practices which I must include in the above code, please let me know.

Do I need to call sleep() exclusively in the code or is it not required?

In C, we would call Sleep() after calling CreateThread() to begin the execution of the    thread.

Regarding the crash: When the above Perl code crashes unexpectedly and sporadically, I get the error message: "Perl command line interpreter has stopped working"

Details of the crash:

```
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Exception Code: c0000008
```

The above exception code corresponds to: STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE

Maybe this corresponds to invalid handle of the thread.

Details of my Perl Installation:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 14 subversion 2) configuration:

Platform:
osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.2, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
useithreads=define
```

Details of the OS: Win 7 Ultimate, 64-bit OS.

Hope this information would be sufficient to find the root cause of the issue and correct the code.

Comment: +1 for thoroughly investigating before calling out for help

Comment: How large is your URL file?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `$mech->success` instead of wrapping the call in a `eval` and checking `$@`?

Comment: Also, if you want to stagger the start of each thread, the `sleep` needs to go in the `while` loop, not `sub1`

Comment: How large is your URL file? The memory footprint of each Perl thread is the same as the memory footprint of the calling process. Launching too many threads will crash your program.

Comment: Thanks Zaid. Yeah, I usually wrap the calls inside eval to trap the errors. I am not sure whether I need to use sleep() in the first place or not. My intention is not to stagger the start of the thread. I am trying to understand the exact usage of join method of the thread object.

Comment: @mob: The URL file is very small. It consists of only 7 URLs. And even then the program crashes sometimes. I have run the same code multiple times, it crashes on few occasions while runs successfully in other cases.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion: asynchronous code using one of the many modules like POE or AnyEvent will make it programm use less memory. Threading in Perl 5 is generally not recommended but used on Windows to emulate forking.

Comment: Does this work on a Linux-based terminal?  I've had issues multi-threading WWW protocol calls on Win 7 (using Selenium) but they run as expected on Linux.

Comment: Have you considered using HTTP::Async if your use case really is fetching URLs? It's not multi-threaded but it is asynchronous which gets you most of the way there to fast downloading of internet content.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It may be that your expectations are a little too high.

Perl's threads are implemented by creating several interpreter instances within the same operating system process. This isolates the Perl code in each thread from all the others (it's share-nothing). What it doesn't (and can't) do is isolate code that's not under perl's control. That is, any module with a component written in C. For example, a quick look at WWW::Mechanize shows that it has the ability to use zlib for compression, if it's installed. If that gets used, and that C code is not sufficiently thread-safe, that can be a possibly-crashing problem. So if you want to be sure that your Perl application will work well under threads, you have to go through all modules it uses (and all the modules *they* use) and check that they either have no non-Perl parts or that those parts are thread-safe. For most nontrivial programs, that's an unreasonable amount of work (or an unreasonable limitation on what CPAN modules you can use).

Which is probably a large part of the reason why threads aren't used all that much in Perl.

Comment: I think it very likely the module is at fault here. I'd suggest you make this point at the top of your answer since it's hidden in the middle at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I've used multi-threading extensively in perl to build large systems. 
The section where you start threads and wait for them to finish looks good to me.

To answer your questions:

- Sleep is not required.
- The way you are calling join is correct, it'll basically block till all threads finish.

I'd do the following:

- Try to comment out the mechanize code. Just to make sure it's not the one causing this. Have a random sleep maybe inside the function instead. See if your script still crashes.
- Try to remove multi threading and see if calling the function multiple times (have a for loop or something) causes any issues.

Answer (score 0):

One little "best practices" thing which jumped out at me was that you are using three parameter open (good) but a bareword filehandle (boo!). I always tend to use "and" and "or" instead of "&&" and "or," too. They are the lowest precedence operators, so are (for me, at least) the easiest to use to correctly split commands. I tend to use && and || only inside the ternary operator or on the right hand side of an equals, like my $a = func() || 'default';

So that open line I'd write:

```
open my $input, '<', 'urls.txt; or die "Couldn't open `urls.txt' for read: $!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use reusable threads approach instead. See this example: [Reusable threads demo](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=691785)

Also check excellent Thread::Queue module:

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $pq = Thread::Queue->new();

my $config = { number_of_threads => 10 };
my @threads = map { threads->create( \&worker, $q, $pq ) }
  ( 1 .. $config->{number_of_threads} );
push @threads, threads->create( \&controller, $q, $pq );

my @urls = read_urls($filename);

foreach my $url (@urls) {

    process_url( $q, $url );
}

while ( my $pend = $q->pending() ) {

    sleep 1;
}

$q->enqueue(undef) for @threads;

while ( my $pend = $pq->pending() ) {

    sleep 1;
}

$pq->enqueue(undef);

foreach my $thr (@threads) {

    $thr->join();
}

sub worker {
    my ( $q, $pq ) = @_;
    while ( my $url = $q->dequeue() ) {

        my $result = check_url($url);
        $pq->enqueue($result);
    }

    printf "Finishing tid(%s)\n", threads->tid;
    return;
}

sub controller {
    my ( $q, $pq ) = @_;
    while ( my $result = $pq->dequeue() ) {

        save_result($result);
    }

    printf "Finishing Controller tid(%s)\n", threads->tid;
    return;
}

sub process_url {
    my ( $q, $url ) = @_;

    $q->enqueue($url);
    return;
}
```